# Generic methods in java. How to match generic parameters

Tags: java, generics, casting, type-inference, entity-relationship

I have this entity-relation model:

```
// Entity interface
public interface Entity<Reference extends Entity<Reference>> extends Iterable<Attribute<Reference, ?>> {

    // set a referrer and the RelationMetadata to this Entity
    <Referrer extends Entity<Referrer>> void setReferrer(RelationMetadata<Referrer, Reference> relationMetadata, Referrer referrer);

    some other methods...

}

// Relation Metadata is a relation descriptor
public class RelationMetadata<Referrer extends Entity<Referrer>, Reference extends Entity<Reference>> {

    some methods...

}
```

I want to create my Entity ('selectedEntity') reading its metadata, loading its referrers and connect these to 'selectedEntity'. So my usage is that:

```
// obtain the entity metadata
EntityMetadata<E> entityMetadata = EntityManager.getEntityMetadata(selectedEntity.getClass());

// cycle on each relation my entity is reference
for (Iterator<RelationMetadata<? extends Entity<?>, E>> iterator = entityMetadata.getAsReferencesRelationsMetadataIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {

    // for each relation
    RelationMetadata<? extends Entity<?>, E> relationMetadata = (RelationMetadata<? extends Entity<?>, E>) iterator.next();

    // instance dao     
    Dao<?> referrerDao = DaoManager.getDao(relationMetadata.getReferrer());

    some code..

    // select referrer entity
    Entity<?> referrer = referrerDao.selectByKey(...);

    // set referrer to my 'selectedEntity'
    selectedEntity.setReferrer(relationMetadata, referrer);

}
```

The problem is that I obtain this compiling error calling method 'setReferrer':

```
'The method setReferrer(RelationMetadata<Referrer,E>, Referrer) in the type Entity<E> is not applicable for the arguments (RelationMetadata<capture#16-of ? extends Entity<?>,E>, Entity<capture#18-of ?>)'
```

I know that 'referrer' I loaded is correctly connected to 'relationMetadata' but how can I hint that to compiler?

That's a very annoying problem, I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you
G.

Comment: What is the type of `selectedEntity`? I don't see it declared in the code you showed.

Comment: selectedEntity is a generic type itself of type E -> <E extends Entity<E>>

Answer (score 0):

The *problem* is the wildcards. The way `setReferrer` is declared you just will not be able to call it with these wildcards. The `<Referrer>` type argument gets captured differently for the two wildcards.

```
RelationMetadata<? extends Entity<?>, E> relationMetadata;
Entity<?> referrer;

selectedEntity.setReferrer(relationMetadata, referrer);
```

There is no way for the compiler to determine that the two `?`s are the same type. It is not safe to call `setReferrer` with two different wildcards.

Here is a simpler example:

```
static <T> void merge(List<T> a, List<T> b) {}
```

The `<T>` asserts that both `a` and `b` have the same generic type argument. I can call this method like this:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> b = new ArrayList<String>();
merge(a, b);
```

Obviously I cannot call it like this:

```
List<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Double> b = new ArrayList<Double>();
merge(a, b);
```

But also I cannot call it like this:

```
List<?> a = new ArrayList<String>();
List<?> b = new ArrayList<String>();
merge(a, b);
```

I can't do that because there's no way to tell that `a` and `b` have the same type argument. (Except by being a person and looking at the code.) And so the compiler captures the wildcards of `a` and `b` as being distinct from each other.

Your types are more complicated but the error you are getting results from the same problem.

I don't know what to tell you except that you have too many wildcards. You need to come up with a way to do whatever it is you are doing that uses less of them. The actual type arguments you are working with need to be passed around more or this routine needs to be part of a parameterized object.

Seeing your comment I think I kind of see what you're doing and you might be able to use a helper method here. This is described in [*"Wildcard Capture and Helper Methods"*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html).

The way it works is:

- assuming the iterator returns any type of `RelationMetadata` on each call to `next`,
- but the process performed does have a singular type (just unknown),
- you can move the loop body in to a separate method that captures the type.

You'd have a helper method something like this:

```
static <R extends Entity<R>, E extends Entity<E>> process(
    RelationMetadata<R, E> relationMetadata,
    Entity<E> selectedEntity
) {
    // not sure what the Dao should be, I guessed
    Dao<R> referrerDao = DaoManager.getDao(relationMetadata.getReferrer());

    ...

    R referrer = referrerDao.selectByKey(...);

    selectedEntity.setReferrer(relationMetadata, referrer);
}
```

In theory doing something like this lets you capture the type of the `RelationalMetadata` and work with it generically. The loop would be refactored to something like this:

```
for(
    Iterator<RelationMetadata<? extends Entity<?>, E>> iterator = (
        entityMetadata.getAsReferencesRelationsMetadataIterator()
    );
    iterator.hasNext();
) {
    process(iterator.next(), selectedEntity);
}
```

Assuming the `selectedEntity` is already generically typed in the context of where this is going on. (I think it would be an `Entity<E>`.) It would complicate things if it were an `Entity<?>` or something like that.

The capturing helper is the "proper" way to do something like this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I only say that. I know the model is correct. Is there any way to say compiler to trust me in this case?
I would like to avoid changing model.

The problem can be simplified in this way.

I have a generic method:
    `<P> void method(P simpleParameter, ComplexParameter<P> complexParameter);`

I know simpleParameter and complexParameter match their generic type P; How I can force it to compiler?
Maybe can I cast parameters in some way? Or can I use a _@SuppressWarnings_ annotation or similar to instruct the compiler?

Comment: I don't really know what to tell you except `relationalMetadata` and `referrer` need to be the same type. So yes if you know the correct types you can cast it. It should also compile if you use raw types instead of wildcards. But I don't recommend it, having to do stuff like that is an indication there is a problem with the design. It can lead to more problems that are difficult to track down. And no, `@SuppressWarnings` will not solve this. This is a straight up compilation error because it's illegal under the language rules.

Comment: The problem with casting is that I don't know what is the runtime value of `Referrer`. I'm cycling on all values and for each I'm doing the same operation (load relation metadata, load referrer) without knowing what is the real type.
I think the problem in model design is that I forced a constraint in method signature that is correct but cannot be verified in all cases.
I don't care what Referrer type is; I only care that two `?` are the same type.

Thank you for your answer. You're very kind.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. I think you can use a capturing helper method here, though it's the kind of thing you might have to tinker with to get it to work (because the typing is a little on the complex side).

Comment: I was just trying a solution like that. Then I read your comment and thank to it I fix my code. Youur solution works. My code now correctly compile. Thank you for your help.